# Law of Gaussian Vector and Matrix

Tags: matrices, random-variables

I have a probability problem that I’m struggling with. Any help would be appreciated.

I have no clue about how to solve this.

Here is the problem:

Let A be:
\begin{pmatrix} 4 & 7 \\ 1 & -2 \end{pmatrix}

X is a normal variable of mean 1 and Y of mean 2

Covariance Matrix of (X,Y):
\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 1 \\ 1 & 2 \end{pmatrix}

What is the law of A * (X,Y) ?

Regards,

Comment: Denote $Z=[X Y]^T$
Compute the characteristic function : $\mathbb{E}[e^{i\langle v, AZ\rangle}]$

Comment: Hi Bertrand, can you show me how to do so ? I have to admit I don't know... Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so $Z=[X,Y]^T$ is a gaussian vector with covariance $C$, mean $m=[1,2]^T$ (Your covariance matrix) and A is another given matrix.

First of all you can write $Z=m+\Gamma w$ where $w$ is a Gaussian vector with mean $0$ and covariance $Id$, and $\Gamma^T\Gamma=C$

For the sake of simplicity, just assume that you know that the characteristic function of 
$w\sim\mathcal{N}(0,Id)$ is $g_{(0,Id)}(v)=\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^2 v_i^2 \right)=\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}v^T (Id) v \right)$

$$g_{(m,C)}=\mathbb{E}[e^{iv^TZ}]=\mathbb{E}[e^{iv^T(m+\Gamma w)}]=e^{iv^Tm}\mathbb{E}[e^{i(\Gamma v)^Tw}]=e^{iv^Tm}g_{(0,Id)}(\Gamma v)=\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}(\Gamma v)^T (Id) (\Gamma v) \right)$$
And 
$$g_{(m,C)}=\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2} v^T \Gamma^T\Gamma v \right)=\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2} v^T C v \right)$$

Now try to see what happens with $AZ$ with the same procedure

Comment: Sorry to look so stupid, but the procedure appear as obscure to me. Can you try to detail with the numbers please ? (it's not that I don't want, it's that I am really not comfortable with the topic).

Comment: It seems that, you are missing the basic background in probabilities. You should try to find references to read about Gaussian random variables, characteristic functions and then it should be more clear. But I can't explain prob. from the beginning. Here the idea is just that the characteristic function tells you what the Gaussian is, so if you can compute the characteristic function of $AZ$ you will be able to tell what is the distribution, and it will be a Gaussian. You have to tell what will be the mean and the covariance.

Comment: Bertrand, I have a basic background in probabilities. But not on Gaussian rv. What I asked for is the way to write this characteristic function when applied to my problem. It would have made my understanding clearer.